# $\cos(\pi x) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, infinite-product

I need to show that $$ \cos(\pi x) = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2}\right)$$.

For $x \notin  \mathbb Z$ one can use $\cos(\pi x ) = \frac{\sin(2 \pi x )}{2 \sin(\pi x )}$ and the fact that $$ \sin(\pi x) = \pi x \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$ I am not sure how to prove the equality in the case $x \in  \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the Identity theorem from complex analysis. If they are equal on an open set (in fact on any set with limit points), then they are equal everywhere.

Think of them as complex functions. $$\prod_{n=0} ^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{(n+1/2)^2}\right )$$ gives you an entire function since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ (n+1/2)^2}$ coverges.

You have shown that for all $z \not \in \mathbb N$, the product equals to an entire function $\cos z$. Therefore, they are equal for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

**Edit**: To avoid complex analysis, note that $\prod _{n=0} ^{\infty}\left( 1 - \frac{x^2} {(n+1/2)^2} \right)$ is a continuous function, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ (n+1/2)^2}$ converges. If you have proven the result for all $x \not \in \mathbb N$, then the result simply extends by continuity.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in the course of my studies I am not "supposed" to be familiar with complex analysis. This problem is supposed to be solved using only tools of the real analysis.

Comment: See if the edit helps you

Comment: But the product is not convergent for all $x=\pm (2p+1), \, p \in \mathbb{N}$, since in this case a certain factor is zero.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: you mean p+1/2 right? But if a certain factor is zero, does it obviously not converge to zero? Don't confuse the sum log definition for product, that is valid only for a non-zero sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x=\pm (p+1/2), \, p \in \mathbb{N}$ then one factor is equal to $0$ in this case does the infinite product converge? No confusion. Please, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: Well, we allow zero here.

Comment: In fact there are theorems like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem, where there are term in teh product that are zero. The common thing in complex analysis is to allow zero. We always allow zero.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal Could you please provide mode details on why the infinite product in the edit section is continuous?